# nao consigo instanciar um objeto a partir de um pacote de assets(asset bundle)

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using ModIO;
using UnityEngine;

public class ModScript : MonoBehaviour{
public string bundleName = "modbundle";

private void Start()
{
LoadMods();
}

public void LoadMods()
{
List<string> mods = ModManager.GetInstalledModDirectories(true);

for (int i = 0; i < mods.Count; i++)
{
    string mod = mods[i];
    Debug.Log("Loaded mod " + Path.GetFileName(mod));
    
    string modpath = Path.Combine(mod, bundleName);
    
    var loaded = AssetBundle.LoadFromFile(modpath);
    if (loaded == null)
    {
        Debug.LogError("Failed to load mod " + mod);
        return;
    }
    
    GameObject[] loadedAssets = loaded.LoadAllAssets();

    foreach (GameObject player in loadedAssets)
    {
        if (player.name == "player")
        {
            Instantiate(player);
        }
    }
   }
 }
}
```

erro na linha 13: Assets \ Scripts \ ModScript.cs (13,6): erro CS1597: Ponto e vírgula após o método ou bloco de acesso não é válido

erro na linha 33

O QUE EU JÁ TENTEI FAZER:

1-Eu tento mudar GameObject para Object, mas o objeto não instancia, eu uso pacotes de assets e mod.io nesta classe, supostamente, eu compilo o pacote de assets e comprimo(zip), eu carrego para o mod.io e faço o download atraves do navegador de mods do mod.io o qual esta integrado dentro do jogo.

2-`loaded.LoadAllAssets<GameObject>();`